# Zooming image in gesture recogniser ios goes out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, pinchzoom, uipinchgesturerecognizer, swift5

I am trying to zoom image within frame of image i added a view in which i add 2 images one is frame and one is image that pinch zoomed code is working successfully but image goes out of view when zoomed. here is my code

```
      @objc func pinchRecognized(pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
           if let view = pinch.view {
               view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: pinch.scale, y: pinch.scale)
               pinch.scale = 1
           }
       }
```

Comment: So what's your question?  Que es tu pregunta?

Comment: i want to bound zoomed image in my view not out of bound